# GMAP : Directions "from" multiple locations to a single "to" location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use Google Map, for Direction to a POI, from multiple POI's.
Can it be done with GMAP?

I have seen example where we can provide multiple destinations or stopovers. But I want to have  a single Destination and multiple Source location.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Assume multiple source as destinations and your single destination as origin. And use google map API for single source multiple destinations.

Ultimately map will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the directions service to find the routes.

You would have to use a different request for each source and show them separately on the map.